# VS2012 shortcut add new class file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, shortcut

Hi have tried to google this, but it is not giving any working tips.

Is there anybody outh there that can tell me the keyboard shortcut for adding a new class file in Visual Studio 2012?

**Edit**: My setup was a fresh install of: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pro, with setup C#

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can define it by your own via `Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Keyboard -> Project.AddClass`

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Select the project in which you want to add `Class` and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. To add a `New Item`, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

You should be using `Visual C# 2005 keyboard scheme` in Visual Studio to have this working. *If you are using other keyboard scheme*, go to run and type `devenv.exe /resetsettings` and when you *restart* Visual Studio it will ask a default keyboard scheme to use where you can select `Visual C#` scheme and then the keyboard shortcuts should be working.

For more list of VS 2012 Keyboard shortcuts refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/da5kh0wa.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, like in menu `Project`>`Add Class...`

Comment: Sorry, its not working.
Is there something that I have to enable to get this working?

Comment: May be your IDE is not configured for C#. Do you see `Add Class...`in menu `Project` (4th menuitem) ?

Comment: Ok, I can add a class if I go via
ALT -> Project -> Add class.

Comment: do you have a shortcut shown in the submenu ? (default is `Shift+Alt+C` but for some reasons, you can have different configuration)

Comment: Hmmm, when looking into options for keayboard, (the above screen) its seems that the shortcut is missing. I have now added it and its workig. 
Tnx for your help!